# rollapply gives one and the same value

Tags: r

I wanted to use `rollapply` in order to build a rolling window for Value at Risk function. I use the following code:

```
var<-rollapply(phelix, width=1000, FUN=function(x) VaR(R=phelix, p=0.95, method="historical"),by=1, by.column=TRUE )
```

phelix is the name of the data vector with returns. It is 3995 observations. I wanted to use a rolling window with 1000 observations. Starting from 1001 and executing the VaR function for every single observation onwards.

After executing the rollapply function I get a vector with 2996 one and the same values. It seems that my window has stuck and doesn't roll :)

Can you please help me with that? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rollapply repeated calls the function you supply to it with a vector that contains data within the rolling window.  In your case you supply `FUN=function(x)`, so x will contain the data within the window.  However the function you define has no reference to x so so it always returns the same thing.  Assuming that the first argument to `VaR` is the one that should receive the rolling data, you should use: `var<-rollapply(phelix, width=1000, FUN=function(x) VaR(R=x, p=0.95, method="historical"),by=1, by.column=TRUE )`

Comment: Thank you so much, Jay! The things look so easy when s.o. explains them. I am a member of "Stackoverflow" for some days now. I asked 2 questions and get a straight answer so quickly. You are awesome guys! I hope that one day I will not only ask, but give answers, too :)

Comment: Ah! I didn't know about this option.